# Magento 2.1.3: Store view config doesn't inherit website config

Tags: magento2, multistore, configuration, magento-2.1.3, core-config-data

As an example - currency config. I setup currency configuration on a website, the currency setup for a store view is set "Use Website". But it shows the config from a default.

The same happens with other settings as well.

**Question:** Am i missing some setting?

***Setup***

**Website - Store - Store view**

- Sweden

  - Sweden

    - Svenska
    - English
- Finland

  - Finland

    - English

**Currency setup**

1) **Catalog Price Scope** (Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Price)

Catalog Price Scope = **website**

2) **Currency Setup** (Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Currency Setup)

- Default Config: Base Currency = **SEK**, Default Display Currency = **SEK**, Allowed Currencies = **SEK, EUR**
- **Sweden**(*Website*): Base Currency = **SEK**, Default Display Currency = **SEK**, Allowed Currencies = **SEK**
- **Finland**(*Website*): Base Currency = **EUR**, Default Display Currency = **EUR**, Allowed Currencies = **EUR**

[image]

***Result:***
In Finland-English store view the currency is ***SEK***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was a bug in Magento 2.1.3 - [#7840](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7840)

Answer (score 1):

Described behavior is correct and on Store View level you must see values from Website level. I've checked that behavior on latest `develop` branch and it is as expected.

Here is my configuration:

**Website**
[image]

**Store View**
[image]

**core_config_data**
[image]

There is a bug on 2.1.3 which already fixed in develop.

There is GitHub issue connected to this bug [#7943](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7943) and link to commit with fix in the comments.